# Getting strange results when trying to capture output with subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess

Using OS: Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601] (windows 7)
Using python version: 3.7.2

I am trying to use the subprocess module to run some commands, and get their output so that I can parse it and automate based on it. But when testing with capturing output, I encountered some strange results.

I ran this code:

```py
import subprocess;

command = subprocess.run(["dir"], shell=True, text=True, capture_output=True);

print(command.stdout);
```

And got this output:

```
$ pytest.py
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is [redacted]

 Directory of C:\Users\[redacted]\tmp

25.05.2019  00:37    <DIR>          .
25.05.2019  00:37    <DIR>          ..
18.01.2017  15:25            16ÿ648 Install-WMF5.1.ps1
25.05.2019  18:47               142 pytest.py
13.01.2017  10:07        68ÿ054ÿ745 Win7AndW2K8R2-KB3191566-x64.msu
               3 File(s)     68ÿ071ÿ535 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  563ÿ220ÿ533ÿ248 bytes free
```

as you can see, there are these strange "ÿ" characters replacing some spaces. But strangely, not all spaces.

What causes this? is it a problem? how can I reliably capture output?

Answer (score 0):

Use `check_ouput` instead of `run` to launch `cmd.exe` with the `/u` flag to encode the result as UTF-16.

Then `decode` it:

```
import subprocess

output = subprocess.check_output('cmd.exe /u /c "dir"').decode('utf-16')

print(output)
```